# How strong is separation + reflection of unbounded quantifiers?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, axioms

Consider a [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_set_theory) with the following axioms:

1. [separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification): $\exists y \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \phi \land x \in a)$ where $y$ is not free in $\phi$
2. [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle): $\phi \to \exists u \phi^u$

where $\phi^u$ bounds all *unbounded* quantifiers in $\phi$ to $u$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528459/does-relativization-of-formulas-replace-bounded-quantifiers-or-not)). This theory proves:

| Result | Parameters | Formula $\phi$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| existence |  | $\top$ |
| [pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing) | $a,b$ | $\exists x (x = a) \land \exists x (x = b)$ |
| [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union) | $a$ | $\forall x_{\in a} \forall y_{\in x} \exists z (z = y)$ |
| [infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity) | $a$ | $\exists x (x = a) \land \forall x \exists y (x \in y \land \forall z_{\in y} (z = x))$ |
| [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement#Collection) for a [$\Delta_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy#Definitions) formula $\psi$ | $a$ | $\forall x_{\in a} \exists y \psi$ |
| [transitive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_model) for a $\Delta_0$ formula $\psi$ |  | $\psi \land \forall x \forall y_{\in x} \exists z (z = y)$ |

What is the consistency strength and interpretability strength of this theory? Can it prove full collection? Has it been studied in the literature?

Comment: Are you working in a language with bounded quantifiers as primitive syntactic objects different from unbounded quantifiers? In the standard first-order language of set theory, bounded quantifiers are just abbreviations for certain constructs using normal (unbounded) quantifiers, hence it is syntactically impossible to relativize unbounded quantifiers, but not bounded quantifiers. I think your confusion in the other question stems from the fact that normally the relativization notation $\phi^u$ is used only when $u$ is *transitive* and all parameters of the formula belong to $u$, ...

Comment: ... in which case relativizing bounded quantifiers does not actually do anything: when $a\in u$ and $u$ is transitive, then $\exists x\in u\,(x\in a\land\psi^u)$ is equivalent to $\exists x\,(x\in a\land\psi^u)$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek See the quote from reference 3 in the linked question. One can branch on the structure of the formula inside the quantifier, allowing one to relativize unbounded quantifiers only.

Comment: Sure you can do that. But this will recognize only one particular form as a “bounded” quantifier, while its trivial syntactic modifications will still count as “unbounded”. Thus, for example, $(\exists x\,(x\in a\land\psi))^u=\exists x\,(x\in a\land\psi^u)$, while $(\exists x\,(\psi\land x\in a))^u=\exists x\in u\,(\psi^u\land x\in a)$. Is this really what you want? The only robust way of defining the relativization of formulas is to relativize *all* quantifiers, while keeping in mind that relativized bounded quantifiers (of whatever form) can be simplified for transitive $u$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, it only captures bounded quantifiers written in the standard way.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Adopting the reflection schema in the question is equivalent to adopting the schema $\phi \to \exists u (\text{transitive}(u) \land \phi^u)$ where $\phi^u$ bounds all quantifiers?

Comment: Yes. In particular, your reflection schema implies its variant where $u$ is transitive: given $\phi$, let $\psi$ be $\phi\land\forall x\,\forall y\in x\,\exists z\,z=y$. Then $\phi\to\psi$, and $\psi^u\to(\phi^u\land u\text{ is transitive})$. Also, in either version of the reflection schema, you may assume $u$ to contain all parameters $x_i$ of $\phi$, by applying it to the conjunction of $\phi$ with the formulas $\exists z\,z=x_i$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This theory is mutually interpretable with second-order arithmetic $\mathsf{Z}_2$ and $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{PowerSet}$ (and hence equiconsistent with them). Note that the mentioned theories are well-known to be mutually interpretable: the interpretation of $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{PowerSet}$ in $\mathsf{Z}_2$ is achieved by carriying out the construction of $L$.

Trivially your theory is a subtheory of $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{PowerSet}$ and hence is interpretable there. The non-trivial part of interpreting $\mathsf{Z}_2$ in your theory is to show there that there is a model of second-order Peano arithmetic (in the signature with just the successor).

For that you simply take any set $A$ such that it contains an empty set and for any $x\in A$ there is a set of the form $\{x\}\cup x\in A$, i.e. it satisfies $$(\exists x\in A)(\forall y\in x) y\ne y \land (\forall x\in A)(\exists y\in A)((\forall z\in x)z\in y \land (\forall z\in y)(z=x\lor z\in x)).$$ Then you consider (set-encoded) binary relations $E$ on $A$ s.t. $x_1 \mathrel{E} x_2$, for all empty $x_1,x_2\in A$ and for every $x_1 \mathrel{E} x_2$ and $y_1,y_2$ of the shapes $\{x_1\}\cup x_1$, $\{x_2\}\cup x_2$ we have $y_1\mathrel{E} y_2$. Then you construct a least binary relation $E_0$ like this. For this you, starting from a Cartesian square $U$ of $A$ (a set containing at least one presentation of pair $(x,y)$, for all $x,y\in A$), construct the set $E_0\subseteq U$ that consists of all $z\in U$ of the form $(x,y)$ such that some presentation of $(x,y)$ is in every binary relation of the considered form. You put $N$ to be the subset of $A$ consisting only of $E_0$-reflexive points. Finally you define the successor relation $x \mathsf{R} y$ to be $(\exists x',y'\in N)(x\mathrel{E} x'\land y\mathrel{E} y'\land \text{$y'$ is of the shape $\{x'\}\cup x'$})$. The structure $(N,E,S)$, where $E$ serves as equality clearly will be a model of second-order Peano arithmetic.

Your theory doesn't prove collection. In fact even the extension of Zermelo set theory with choice $\mathsf{ZC}$ by your reflection principle doesn't prove collection. For this let me show that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves consistency  of this theory. We cosider an $\omega$-sequence of ordinals $\omega=\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\ldots$ such that each $\alpha_{n+1}$ is least such that for every transitive model $M$, there is a transitive model $M'\in V_{\alpha_{n+1}}$ for which $M\cap V_{\alpha_n}=M'\cap V_{\alpha_n}$ and $M$ and $M'$ satisfy the same first-order formulas with parameters from $M\cap V_{\alpha_n}$. It is easy to see that for $\alpha_\omega=\lim_{n<\omega} \alpha_n$ the model $V_{\alpha_\omega}$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZC}$ togethe r with reflection.

Don't know if this theory was studied.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know of a similar reflection axiom that yields a stronger theory?

Comment: Yes, sure, $\varphi\to\exists u(\varphi^u\land (\forall x\in u)(\psi(x)\mathrel{\leftrightarrow} \psi^u(x)))$. It implies collection over pure first-order logic.

Comment: Two formulas in the schema... Is it possible to simplify that somehow?

Comment: Indeed there is a room for simplification, the schemata $\exists u(\forall x\in u)(\psi(x)\mathrel{\leftrightarrow}\psi^u(x))$ is equivalent to the previous one.

Comment: Nice. So just separation + $\exists u (\forall x \in u) (\psi(x) \leftrightarrow \psi^u(x))$ (where $\psi^u$ bounds unbounded quantifiers) seems to create a pretty powerful theory. Is the exact strength of this theory known? (I can ask a separate question if you'd like.)

Comment: It will be exactly of the same strength as second-order arithmetic. If you add power set, then you get a theory mutually interpretable with $\mathsf{ZFC}$. By the way, separation could be restricted to just $\Delta_0$ formulas. There is no need to ask a separate question.

Comment: So, to be clear, it's stronger only in the sense of proving more consequences (e.g. full collection), but does not increase interpretability or consistency strength?

Comment: Indeed, over full separation there is no difference in interpretability/consistency/proof-theoretic strength. However, if you would weaken the separation to $\Delta_0$ formulas, my reflection principle would still be sufficient to recover the full separation. Wheres your reflection principle combined with $\Delta$-sepration would result in a theory mutually interpretable with  ${\sf KP}\omega$ (your theory is mutually interpretable with ${\sf ACA}_0+$ $\omega$-model reflection, which is equivalent to bar induction ${\sf BI}$ and is mutually interpretable with Kripke-Platek).